# Método prompt JS - 'if' 'else if'

Tags: javascript

Ainda sou leigo em JS, mas essa questão acredito ser simples, pretendo se caso o usuário digite um valor numérico ao invés de letras, ele escreva na tela 'Instancia errada!' e se caso ele digite alguma letra diferente do meu nome 'Elienay' ele retornasse para pergunta, voltasse a repetir ela

```js
var name = prompt("Digite seu nome:","");
if (name=="Elienay") {
document.write("Exato");
}
else if(name== 0 to 999){
 document.write("Instancia errada!");
}
else if(name != "Elienay"){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `match` para validar a entrada, passando uma regex.

Para repetir sempre que a entrada não for válida encapsule o código numa fune a chame

```js
(function ask() {
  var name = prompt("Digite seu nome:", "");

  if (name.match(/Elienay/i)) {
    document.write("Exato");
  } else if (name.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
    document.write("Instancia errada!");
  } else if (name != "Elienay") {
    ask();
  }
})();
```

Comment: Se caso for uma letra ou uma sequencia diferente do meu nome, ele tem que fazer o retorno, repetir a pergunta, o que deu certo no seu código foi caso digite um numero

Comment: no final, não é para ele escrever nada, pois caso digite algum letra fora do meu nome e alguma letra fora da sequencia, ele tem que repetir a pergunta, entendeu..

Comment: e pelo que parece ele está considerando errado caso eu digite meu nome com a primeira letra minuscula

Comment: Editei a pergunta adicionando